# Puppy Linux on laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 (dual-boot)?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, puppy-linux, acer

I just read about Puppy Linux the other day. The latest release is called Tahrpup, and is partially built from Trusty Tahr (Ubuntu 14.04). So now I am curious, and I would like to install it on my laptop. **Is it possible to do this as a dual-boot installation?**

Actually I guess it would be a treble-boot (or whatever the correct term is) because I already have Windows on here. (The laptop came with Windows pre-installed. I had Ubuntu installed in another partition, and I never never use Windows.) **How could I do this so that I will still use the grub from Ubuntu?**

My laptop specs:
*Acer Aspire

3.2 GiB memory

AMD A6-1450 APU with Radeon HD Graphics × 4

Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI 

64-bit OS

378.7 GB disk space*

Comment: You can install as many OS'es as you can make (root-)partitions for. I don't know Puppy Linux, so I can't answer the how part.

Comment: Why do you want to install puppy linux on a laptop?  As far as I recall, that's a distro that's specifically designed to install on a flash drive or CD to debug other computers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have as many operating systems installed as you have space for. There's nothing special about Puppy, just install it as you would any other distribution.

You can either create a partition for it before installing or use its installer to create one during installation (I've never installed Puppy but presumably its installer will offer this choice).

As for using Ubuntu's GRUB, you have two options:

1. Install Puppy's GRUB which should also recognize the other 2 systems, then reboot into Ubuntu and run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

   Make sure to change `/dev/sda` to wherever your GRUB is actually installed. It is usually, but not always, `/dev/sda`. This will make Ubuntu's GRUB locate Puppy and will overwrite Puppy's GRUB with Ubuntu's.
2. Tell your Puppy installation not to install a boot loader. When you reboot, you'll only see Ubuntu's GRUB and you won't see Puppy. Boot into Ubuntu and then run the same two commands I show above. They will refresh Ubuntu's GRUB and make it see Puppy.